# Webpack 2 Split Polyfills into own bundle

Tags: webpack-2, code-splitting

I'm trying to use `require.ensure` to cause Webpack 2 to create separate bundles containing polyfills for older browsers.

I was of the understanding that the following code would cause a new bundle `whatwgFetch` to be created and loaded:

```
require.ensure([], (require) => {
    require('whatwg-fetch')
}, 'whatwgFetch')
```

Webpack outputs that only one bundle is created, and when I inspect it I can see the `whatwg-fetch` module has been included within.

My assumptions are based on the Webpac 2 code splitting guide: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-require/

What else should I do to cause webpack to create and load a separate bundle?

Answer (score 1):

I was importing the `whatwg-fetch` elsewhere in the application, which was causing webpack to correctly bundle it in with the rest of the code, in one single bundle.

Removing these extra imports caused it to work correctly